# N98 magerun Command Issue - Magento 1.9x

Tags: magento, command, command-line-interface, magento-1.9

I am using the n98-magerun version 1.101.1 for my Magento 1.9x version. When I execute this command **php n98-magerun.phar rewrites:analysis:top** then it shows

```
[Exception]
Table 'my_database.core_url_rewrite' doesn't exist query
```

I have found that the issue is because its not considering the table prefix. Why?

My actual name of table with prefix is **mg_core_url_rewrite**. But when I execute any kind of n98-magerun command then it always considers without prefix like **core_url_rewrite**.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

mesk,

There is one issue like you get it, You will get solution here, Please check it https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/994

If you have any trouble then let me know.

Comment: Hi, I have only reported this issue.